# Disk drill is showing files, but they are not accessible in finder

Tags: macos, xcode, file

I'm having the common issue where I have a ridiculous amount of storage taken up by "other", and have enlisted disk drill to help work out where the culprits are.

In disk drill, I have ~90Gb taken up by by library, 83Gb of which is attributed to `~\InstallerSandboxes\.PKInstallSandboxManager\` which then holds six folders, all of which are from what look like Xcode updates (`folder\root\application\` is `Xcode.app` in all six)

[image: disk drill screengrab]

I tried restarting in safe mode to clear the caches, however storage still is showing 100Gb+ in other, and disk drill shows the same image, however now when I navigate to the folder in finder, none of the folders within `\.PKInstallSandboxManager\` are visible, and the folder itself, along with the other file in `\InstallerSandboxes\` are greyed out.

[image: finder]

I've made sure that hidden files / folders are visible, and have found various other threads about folders being inaccessible, and have tried to amend the folder date as this seems to be a recurring issue using `SetFile -d ...`, but get the following error:

```
❯ SetFile -d '10/10/2021 00:00:00'/Library/Apple/System/Library/InstallerSandboxes/.PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware
ERROR: Unexpected Error. (-5000)  on file: /Library/Apple/System/Library/InstallerSandboxes/.PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware
```

From here I tried changing permissions in the various folders in the path but that's not fixed it. I've also tried moving the folder in terminal to a Temp folder using `mv /Library/Apple/System/Library/InstallerSandboxes/* /Users/<username>/Desktop/Temp`, however that gives the error `zsh: no matches found: /Library/Apple/System/Library/InstallerSandboxes/*`

I'm at a total loss as to where to go from here and can't deal with 80+Gb being lost.

Comment: I am not sure what effect deleting these directories has on the system. It would be nice to do a Time Machine backup or a system clone first. What is your system version? You can try suppress this folders from the terminal in Recovery mode (cmd+r at boot). Then you can navigate to /Volumes/Name_Volume/Library//Apple/System/Library/InstallerSandboxes/.PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware and try suppress directories with `rm -r *activeSandbox`

Comment: I’ve tried your suggestion however and just get `rm:*activeSandbox: No such file or directory `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few things after this - booting in recovery as per Jean_JD's suggestion, but that didn't show any of the folders within `.PKInstallSandboxManage`. I tried just `rm -r .PKInstallSandboxManage` which made the folder disappear in terminal whilst in recovery, but the folder was back once I rebooted properly.

What seemed to finally do the trick was dragging the `.PKInstallSandboxManage` folder into a new note in apple notes, waiting a couple of seconds and then double clicking on the hyperlink that appeared.

`.PKInstallSandboxManage` is still greyed out, but the internal folders became accessible and I could then delete them from my system.